# When did Wang Mingzhang die?

Tags: military, 20th-century, china

[Wang Mingzhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Mingzhang) was a Chinese general of the National Revolutionary Army during the Second Sino-Japanese War. He commanded the defense of Teng County (14-18 March 1938), part of the [Xuzhou Campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Xuzhou), being killed in action.

However, there are multiple dates for his death. Wikipedia says the 14th; [this webpage](http://generals.dk/general/Wang_Mingzhang/_/China.html) says the 17th, and [this webpage](https://ww2db.com/battle_spec.php?battle_id=173) says the 15th.

Exactly which day did he die?

Comment: Interesting question (especially the need for specifics). Given your familiarity with **MacKinnon's _Wuhan, 1938_**, the chronology shows **_March 17th_** (p. 120). But Chinese wikipedia also states as 14th (_1938年3月14日_)

Comment: That chronology gives the date that Teng *xian* falls, and Wang's death in parentheticals. It could imply he died the day of the fall, or some time during the multi-day battle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

March 17 appears to be the correct date.

In the [Chinese Wikipedia article](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BE%90%E5%B7%9E%E4%BC%9A%E6%88%98) on the Xuzhou campaign, the timeline has him dying on the 17th.

His [Baidu biography](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8E%8B%E9%93%AD%E7%AB%A0/4144712) goes into detail about the action on each day of the Battle of Teng County. It describes the Japanese breaching the walls on the 3rd day (16th), before describing Wang's death the following day when he was directing battle in the town centre's crossroads and was struck by multiple bullets.

In 2003, his birthplace of Xindu erected a bronze statue in memory of Wang Mingzhang. They date they chose was March 17.

[image: Wang Mingzhang memorial]

[image: Wang Mingzhang memorial closeup]